# Git Help UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate: warning: Merge conflict: File still marked as conflicted

Tags: git, xcode4

I have a project I have been working on in Xcode 4.4.1, and wanted to go back to a previous Branch.
(Note branches are not complex, but represent a linear development)

When I selected the previous branch there was a warning

```
UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate: warning: Merge conflict: File still marked as conflicted
```

Everything looked OK, but all the build and run menu items are greyed out, so I can't do anything.

I tried to to revert to the latest branch, and this looks OK, but there is still a Merge conflict
    MyProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/ian.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate: warning: Merge conflict: File still marked as conflicted

I have tried a git status, which did not help

```
# Unmerged paths:
...
#   deleted by them:    MyProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace/xcuserdata/ian.xcuserdatad/UserInterfaceState.xcuserstate
#
# Changes not staged for commit:
...
#
#   deleted:    MyProject.xcodeproj/xcuserdata/ian.xcuserdatad/xcschemes/QuollEyeTree.xcscheme
```

I tried a git reset HEAD, but this did not seem to help, and I do not know where to go from here.

Git is handy for checking code against previous versions, but I get into trouble whenever I try to swap versions.

My current problems seem to have been exacerbated when I tried to create a workspace and add another project.
The original project was created under Xcode 3 and the project and files are immediately under the project directory.

EDIT - Resolved

The answers below did not resolve the issue, but both were helpful.

I saved my code from the project directory, removed the latest branch with

```
git reset --hard HEAD~1
```

then copied the changed files back to the project directory

I also updated my .gitignore (which I thought I had done before)

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem you had after resolving my conflicts and this is how I fixed it.
If you use Xcode to keep track of your git repo try the following.
1. I resolved all the conflicts then saved the resolved files.
2. Go to File -> Source Control -> Mark As Resolved

Voila Xcode no longer recognizes these files as having conflicts. Hopefully this works for someone.

Comment: Thanks man! That's the best solution I guess, and worked like a charm.

Answer (score 5):

When there is a merge conflict, you MUST resolve it first. (well maybe you can run `git merge --abort` to revert).

So the process is you open your conflicting file, you look for the conflict, resolve it (edit the conflicting lines), then save your file, add it (using `git add -u`) and commit it.

Then you can work on a clean work directory.

By the way, a conflict probably looks like:

```
<<<<<<< yours:sample.txt
Conflict resolution is hard;
let's go shopping.
=======
Git makes conflict resolution easy.
>>>>>>> theirs:sample.txt
```

reference: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-merge.html

Comment: I understand resolving conflicts, but how do I do this for  MyProject.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace This is not shown in Xcode PS The reference looks quite useful

Comment: I suppose you should look at the different files listed, one has probably a conflict. If none has, just stage them for commit (i.e. run `git add`) and commit. You can run a diff before committing to make sure the conflicts are solved. If a file is deleted, you can use `git reset` on it. I don't remember exactly how you should use it but you can look for its reference doc.

Answer (score 5):

Running

```
git mergetool
```

and resolving the conflicts fixed the problem for me.

As a side note I use Command-D to navigate to conflicts, pick a side in bottom right hand corner of FileMerge, then Command-S Command-Q (on Mac) once finished to save and quit.

Comment: all of these years later i thank you, 

mergetool was the only way for me to update a workspace breakpoint file

Comment: For others, you can do "git mergetool -t opendiff" to open Mac's FileMerge tool.

Answer (score 1):

First and foremost, make a good habit of adding `*.xcuserstate` and patterns to ignore other user-specific project files to your `.gitignore`. There's a popular github repo for .gitignore files, including one for Xcode projects.

In addition to resolving merge conflicts (as mentioned), you should also make a good habit to stash your changes while checkout-ing out different heads (branches, tags, etc).